# Cisco EPC3928AD router has lagspikes of dropped packages a few times per minute

Tags: router, troubleshooting

My cable router (a Cisco EPC3928AD EuroDocsis 3.0 I received from my internet provider Ziggo (in the Netherlands)) is having consistent issues with dropping packages.

It drops packages which it passes through to the internet (as a gateway) and that are directed to the IP of the router itself.

The good stuff:

The web interface response at normal speed (except correlating with packet drops) and does not seem to increase or decrease packet loss.
The EuroDocsis noise and power levels are all optimal (averages to 0 dBmV over the channels (half above, rest below), 40+ dB signal to noise ratio).

The bad stuff:

It averages out to slightly less than 1% of packages dropped when measured over a minute or so, measuring was done with Linux flood pinging the local IP of the router, packages are sometimes delayed by up to *4 seconds*.

The ping spikes are visible with standard windows ping as well and show that at the same time as increased ping/dropped packets to the local IP a remote IP shows the same problems (tested with 8.8.8.8).

The troubleshooting:

I am connected to the router via ethernet, I have tried different physical ports on the device. There are several other devices on the network that can be pinged perfectly fine and they have the same problems with pinging the router.

The problems started roughly around the time I installed a set top box for my TV, but disconnecting the set top box (and the cable connecting to it at the earliest option) does not solve the problem.

I have reset the router to factory settings, I have disabled the internal firewall, and I don't know what else to try. Any other tips to try?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try connecting a laptop or pc directly to the ziggo modem and test if it still happens.
2. Also try a speedtest using speedtest.ziggo.nl and look at the graph. If its fluctuating a lot, then it means you have a problem on the line. Also don't use wifi when doing the test.
3. you can always call ziggo. If you have VOIP, call 1200 (free number). They can measure your connection remotely and spot any problems on the line.
4. If you're concerned it is the modem, you can always ask them to set the modem in bridge mode (dutch: je kan echt vragen hem in "bridge modus" te zetten). This will basically turn off the internal router, including wifi, and wifi spots support.
5. In worst case, ziggo can send you a mechanic to replace the modem. Ziggo is not the worst company. If you keep insisting to support that the problem is not gone after you did all their tests (which usually means giving the modem a power cycle) they'll send a mechanic. If they don't see a problem, their first solution is usually to replace the modem.

Comment: 1. As stated I'm connected via ethernet, I don't know how to connect more directly (I am not breaking it open and soldering wires, that sounds like a terrible idea). 2. That doesn't show the problem of intermittent packet loss (they're resend quickly enough) and high ping. 3 and 5. I am asking here to avoid calling support, that's a last resort because ugh calling. 4. I'm kinda fond of it being a router, that allows my 10 or so devices to connect to it. Thanks though

Comment: 1. Ah, normally people call the ziggo modem, a modem. You referred to it as the router, which caused confusion. I assumed your situation was as most people: internet -> ziggo modem -> router. So my suggestion with 1 was to connect your pc to the ziggo modem rather than the 2nd router, but you appear not to have a 2nd router, causing 1 to be n/a.

Comment: Seems like calling support is the best bet here. Its quite likely there's a network issue. 2 will actually show you packet loss because the graph it draws should be close to a straight line. If there's packet loss, it will show big fluctuations. And if it does that, calling support is the only thing you can do to resolve this problem.